# wxPython: Base class error when using TextEditMixin

Tags: wxpython, listctrl

I was trying to create ListCtrl-derived class to add 2 functions, `set_data` and `_set_column_width`, here is the code:

```
class ListReport(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):

    def __init__(self, parent=None,  columns=['DEFAULT'], size=wx.DefaultSize,
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_VRULES):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, pos, size, style)
        listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
        self.columns = columns
        self.column_index = len(columns)

        self.InsertColumn(0, 'No.')
        for enum, column in enumerate(columns):
            enum += 1
            self.InsertColumn(enum, column)

    def set_data(self, data):
        # Change all data into str
        values = [map(str, value) for value in data]

        for enum, value in enumerate(values):
            enum += 1

            first = self.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, str(enum))

            for x in range(self.column_index):
                if value[x] == None:
                    self.SetStringItem(first, x+1, '-')
                else:
                    self.SetStringItem(first, x+1, value[x])

            # Give ListCtrl some colors
            if first % 2:
                self.SetItemBackgroundColour(first, 'E8E8E8')
            else:
                self.SetItemBackgroundColour(first, '#FBFF94')

        self._set_column_width(data)

    def _set_column_width(self, data=None):
        """Automatically resize column based on data or column header
        if column header longer than data using wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER
        else using data instead.
        """
        for x in range(self.column_index):
            longest = max([len(str(row[x])) for row in data])
            if len(self.columns[x]) + 3 > longest:
                self.SetColumnWidth(x+1, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER)
            else:
                self.SetColumnWidth(x+1, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, 37)
        self.resizeLastColumn(0)
```

Then, I'm using class above to create another class with `TextEditMixin`

```
class ListReportEdit(ListReport, listmix.TextEditMixin):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, columns=['DEFAULT'], size=wx.DefaultSize,
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_VRULES):
        ListReport(parent, columns, size, pos, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)
```

But, I got this error when trying to use it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wxform_sandbox.py", line 263, in <module>
    a = Sandbox()
  File "wxform_sandbox.py", line 27, in __init__
    lr = ListReportEdit(panel, columns, size=(400, 300))
  File "wxform_sandbox.py", line 145, in __init__
    listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib\mixins\listctrl.py", line 451, in __init__
    self.make_editor()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib\mixins\listctrl.py", line 466, in make_editor
    editor = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=style)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_controls.py", line 1736, in __init__
    _controls_.TextCtrl_swiginit(self,_controls_.new_TextCtrl(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: in method 'new_TextCtrl', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'
```

But then, when I'm using `wx.ListCtrl` as base class of `ListReportEdit` instead of `ListReport` it works perfectly, I'm not clearly understand how python inheritance works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you haven't called the parents init method (well, you have, but you're making a new ListReport object)

```
class ListReportEdit(ListReport, listmix.TextEditMixin):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, columns=['DEFAULT'], size=wx.DefaultSize,
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_VRULES):
        ListReport.__init__(self,parent, columns, size, pos, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Ahh..my bad, I'm not double-check my code, thanks for noticing it